# cs50 dna pset6 Works on small database but not on large

Tags: python, cs50

This is my solution to CS50 pset6 DNA problem in python. It works fine on small database but gives an

> Index error: List Index Out of range.

I tried print to see where is the error.. It prints out large database as well. Not sure what to do next.

```
import csv
import sys


def main():

    # TODO: Check for command-line usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        print("Usage: python dna.py database.csv sequence.txt")
        sys.exit(1)

    # TODO: Read database file into a variable
    dna_database =[]
    with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as dna_data_file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(dna_data_file)
        for row in reader:
            dna_database.append(row)


    # TODO: Read DNA sequence file into a variable
    with open(sys.argv[2], "r") as load_sequence:
        sequence = load_sequence.read()

    # TODO: Find longest match of each STR in DNA sequence
    STR = list(dna_database[0].keys())[1:]
    STR_match ={}
    for i in range(len(dna_database)):
        # print(dna_database)
        STR_match[STR[i]] = longest_match(sequence,STR[i])

    # TODO: Check database for matching profiles
    for i in range(len(dna_database)):
        matches = 0
        for j in range(len(STR)):
            if int(STR_match[STR[j]]) == int(dna_database[i][STR[j]]):
                matches += 1
                if matches == len(STR):
                    print(dna_database[i]['name'])
                    sys.exit(0)

    print("No Match")

    return


def longest_match(sequence, subsequence):
    """Returns length of longest run of subsequence in sequence."""

    # Initialize variables
    longest_run = 0
    subsequence_length = len(subsequence)
    sequence_length = len(sequence)

    # Check each character in sequence for most consecutive runs of subsequence
    for i in range(sequence_length):

        # Initialize count of consecutive runs
        count = 0

        # Check for a subsequence match in a "substring" (a subset of characters) within sequence
        # If a match, move substring to next potential match in sequence
        # Continue moving substring and checking for matches until out of consecutive matches
        while True:

            # Adjust substring start and end
            start = i + count * subsequence_length
            end = start + subsequence_length

            # If there is a match in the substring
            if sequence[start:end] == subsequence:
                count += 1

            # If there is no match in the substring
            else:
                break

        # Update most consecutive matches found
        longest_run = max(longest_run, count)

    # After checking for runs at each character in seqeuence, return longest run found
    return longest_run


main()
```

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Comment: _"Not sure what to do next."_ [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: dna/ $ python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/8.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/106377431/dna/dna.py", line 84, in <module>
    main()
  File "/workspaces/106377431/dna/dna.py", line 29, in main
    STR_match[STR[i]] = longest_match(sequence,STR[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
dna/ $

Comment: `STR = list(dna_database[0].keys())[1:]` Since you are slicing the list, `len(STR)` is one less than `len(dna_database)` so using `range(len(dna_database))` to index `STR` causes the error.

Comment: Thanks for your input, and please bear with me.. I am quite new to this. But that should create problem with the small database as well. That seems to be working fine

Comment: na/ $ python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/4.txt
Alice
dna/ $

Comment: My comment is a bit incorrect in that `len(STR)` is one less than `len(dna_database[0].keys())`. I can't see the data so you will have to determine why these values are causing problems. Try adding `print(len(STR))` and `print(len(dna_database[0].keys()))` to see if they are different with different data sets.